# Multiple POSTs with one request

Tags: json, c#-4.0, httpwebrequest, httpwebresponse

I have the following code to post data to a remote web service.

The issue is that sometimes on the web service the transaction is logged multiple times. Below is the code:

```cs
public static T HttpPost<T>(string device_id, string outURL, string Accept, string ContentType, string XAuthToken, string JSONData, dynamic IbObject) {
        T response = (T)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T));

        HttpWebRequest Request = null;     //Declare an HTTP-specific implementation of the WebRequest class.
        HttpWebResponse Response = null;

        LogTransaction(outURL, IbObject, HttpIO.output);

        Global.DebugLog.LogMessage("HttpPost", JsonConvert.SerializeObject(IbObject), ErrorLevel.Info);

        byte[] data2 = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(JSONData);

        try
        {
            Request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(outURL);
            Request.Method = "POST";

            Request.Headers.Add("X-OP-TOKEN", LocalACPInformation.urltoken);


            Request.Headers.Add("X-DEVICE-ID", device_id);
            Request.Accept = Accept;
            Request.ContentType = ("application/json; charset=utf-8");
            Request.ContentLength = data2.Length;
            Request.Timeout = (1000000);

            Stream myStream = Request.GetRequestStream();
            myStream.Write(data2, 0, data2.Length);
            myStream.Close();

            Console.WriteLine("Message sent getting response... \n");

            Response = (HttpWebResponse)Request.GetResponse();
            Console.WriteLine(Response.Headers.ToString() + "\n");
            System.IO.StreamReader sr = new System.IO.StreamReader(Response.GetResponseStream());
            string rcv_data = sr.ReadToEnd().Trim();


            IbObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(rcv_data);

            Request.Abort();

            return IberonObject;
        }
```

Comment: Your error probably isn't in that code...  Do you have your own retry logic somewhere else?  You left out the end of the method.

Comment: The catch {} code just catches exception and aborts the connection. I have not tried the code to different server. The strange part is the code works as expected for the most part but during regression testing server starts logging multiple entries for a single POST. Since, I do not have access to the server side code, I am not sure how to handle this.